# How to save model with nested attributes with postman using JSON in a rails-api only app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, postman, rails-api

I am creating a rails-api only app.
I have 2 models User and Account. 
**User** model looks like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
end
```

and my **Accounts** model looks like this,

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**On user create I need to save values to account model as well.
I need to know how to do that using postman.**
The format in which to send data so user gets created and also value get inserted in accounts model.

I am using **postman** to do this.

The error I am geeting in server log is as below

```
Started POST "/auth?email=email000@meail.com&password=[FILTERED]&password_confirmation=[FILTERED]&account[school_name]=mjdhs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-01 12:54:56 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"email000@meail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "account"=>{"school_name"=>"mjdhs"}}
Unpermitted parameter: account
Unpermitted parameter: account
Unpermitted parameter: account
```

Comment: What will really matter here is the Create action in your Users controller (this will determine the accepted form of the incoming data from Postman or any other source, and will allow you to do anything you want with it, such as save multiple objects). Could you post the code from your user_controller.rb?

Comment: @ConnorCMcKee My user controller is handled by devise_auth_token gem which I am using for token based auhtentication.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with with rails but I think I may be able to help you out.  I agree with ConnorCMKee that it would be helpful to see your controller code.
In general your JSON should look something like:

```
{
  userProperty1: userPropertValue1,
  userProperty2: userPropertValue2,
  accounts: [
    {
       accountsProperty1: accountsPropertValue1,
       accountsProperty2: accountsPropertValue2
    }
]}
```

The above has whatever user properties your user class has including an accounts array of account object which in turn should hold the account property value pairs.  Hope this helps.  If you need more help for actually doing the request let me know.

Comment: Please check the serverlog error i am getting. I have added the same at bottom @gartuanTezMaximus

Comment: It looks like your request is making it to the server but it doesn't like how you are representing your account(s) in json.  I'm not famaliar with rails at all so I don't know how much assistance that I can provide.  Can you create an User object and possibly serialize/convert them to Json.  This may give you an idea about the format the json should be in.

Comment: @GuartuanTezMaximus tried it still not working.
Getting unpermitted params error still

Answer (score 0):

You can save nested attributes as JSON in Postman by inserting the parameter like this:

```
"nested-attribute-plural_attributes" : [
    {"attribute" : "value1"},
    {"attribute" : "value2"}
]
```

I will use an "party app" as example. So you want to create a new `party`, and add `hosts` as **nested attributes**. Your Postman request would look like this:

```
{
  "title" : "My birthday party",
  "date" : "26-02-2018",
  "hosts_attributes": [
    {"name" : "Mom"},
    {"name" : "Sister"}
  ]
}
```

Remember that your `parties_controller` must have `hosts_attributes` in permited parameters:

```
def party_params
  params.permit(
    :title,
    :date,
    hosts_attributes: [:name]
  )
end
```